# Throttling in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

throttling rules:

1. if there is no other item emitted in recent 100ms, next item would be deliver to subscriber immediately
2. If not, buffer incoming items, until 1000ms timeout or buffer size reach 500, then deliver buffered item list to subscriber

Can RxJava achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a (theoretical) operator called `conflate()` which does some of this. I have seen several implementations, most recently on [this discussion thread](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4856). Adapting from valeriyo's answer, we develop the following operator:

```
public static <T> Transformer<T, List<T>> adaptiveSample(long time, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
  return source -> source
      .publish(shared -> concat(
          shared.take(1).toList(),
          shared.buffer(500, time, unit, scheduler))
          .repeatWhen(a -> shared.debounce(time, unit, scheduler)));
}
```

You would then apply it using the following:

```
observable
  .compose( adaptiveSample( 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler ) )
  .subscribe( listOfSamples -> doStuff( listOfSamples ) );
```

You will have to test this yourself. I'm not clear on a couple of your assumptions.